# How do I apply a color to a single bar of my single series graph?

Tags: java, jfreechart, paint

I am new to JFreeChart and I am trying to see what action do what.

In my chart I only have one series, and I would like -according to the value- to set a different color for the bar. For example :  `0-20 -> RED, 20-80 -> YELLOW, 80-100 -> GREEN`

```
CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
CategoryDataset dataset = plot.getDataset(0);

Number value = dataset.getValue(dataset.getRowKey(0), dataset.getColumnKey(0));
Double val = value.doubleValue();

if (val <= 20.0) {
    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
    Paint tmp = renderer.getItemPaint(row, column);

    /*
    ** Help Please
    */      
}

return chart;
```

This is where  I reached, I am stuck here and don't know really where to go. I saw in the documentation that Paint is an interface but none of the class implementing this interface does provide a setXXX() method. So, my two questions are :

- How do I set a color to a single Bar ?
- How do I apply that to my chart ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create your own subclass of `BarRenderer` and override [`getItemPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemPaint%28int,%20int%29). Instead of choosing a color based on column, choose it based on your value. Here's an outline to show how the existing `BarRenderer` works.

```
plot.setRenderer(new MyRender());
...
class MyRender extends BarRenderer {

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col) {
        System.out.println(row + " " + col + " " + super.getItemPaint(row, col));
        return super.getItemPaint(row, col);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a question, getItemPaint is supposed to return me a Paint class, but if I want to set a color for a define (row, col) attributes does is still take place in the getItemPaint?

Comment: AFAIK, yes; the API recommends overriding `getItemPaint()` "if you require different behavior." Click on the `getItemPaint()` or `lookupSeriesPaint()` link to see the default implementation.