# Color each bar individually in a grouped, stacked bar chart in jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart, bar-chart

In jfreechart, I have a renderer such as

```
GroupedStackedBarRenderer renderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
```

I my example I have 4 groups of 5 stacked bars (2 bars each stack), all in all 40 bars.

I have used a construction like

```
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0 + 2 * (length * s + g), <color for this bar>);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(1 + 2 * (length * s + g), <color for this bar>);
```

in order to color each bar individually, where g denotes the group, 'length' is the number of groups, s the stacked bar number within the group.

Unfortunately this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create any color scheme you want by overriding `getItemPaint()`, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002959/230513). Note the use of `StandardXYBarPainter`. It may help to print out a few values, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5481556/230513). If not, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your approach.

Comment: I can't see how to select colors for each bar from your answer. but I have found out the following: I'm filling the 40 bars with

Comment: ... categoryset.addValue(value, rowkey, columnkey) and then try to color each bar with renderer.getSeriesPaint(barNumber, color). However, only the first 10 barNumbers (0 to 9) take effect. This corresponds to the first group of bars. The remaining 3 groups of bars are colored the same as the first group. I need a function like setBarPaint() but this apparently does not exist. Could you be a bit more specific, please?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows how you override `getItemPaint()`, as shown in the examples cited.