# JFreeChart How to get date value for CandlestickChart using OHLCSeries

Tags: jfreechart

I generate a JFreeChart CandlestickChart , using OHLCSeries . And I extend CandlestickRenderer. In CandlestickRenderer, I overwrite "public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int item)" , in it I need the every stoke's date info to do something, but I don't know to get it , please help me to solve it.

Part of Codes as following:

```
       OHLCSeries ohlcSeries = new OHLCSeries("Price");
       for(Records record : recordslist ) {
           double h =...;
           ....
           LocalDate actionday = record.getRecordsDay ();
           int year = actionday.getYear();
           int month = actionday.getMonthValue();
           int day = actionday.getDayOfMonth();
           ohlcSeries.add(new Day(day,month,year), open, high, low, close);
       }
       OHLCSeriesCollection candlestickDataset.addSeries(ohlcSeries);
       JFreeChart candlestickChart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart("", "","", candlestickDataset, true);

       DateAxis  dayAxis = new DateAxis (); 
       candlestickChart.getXYPlot().setDomainAxis(dayAxis);

       class AnalysisCandlestickRenderer extends CandlestickRenderer {
            public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int item) {
                //here I need every stoke's date info , how can I get it?
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5481556/230513), you can access the required field in your dataset, an `OHLCSeriesCollection`, using the `series` and `item` values passed to your implementation of `getItemPaint()` in your custom `CandlestickRenderer`. Starting form this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611246/230513), the following renderer produces the data values shown.

Code:

```
private final OHLCSeriesCollection seriesCollection = new OHLCSeriesCollection();
…
class AnalysisCandlestickRenderer extends CandlestickRenderer {

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int item) {
        OHLCSeries currentSeries = seriesCollection.getSeries(series);
        System.out.println(series + ": " + currentSeries.getPeriod(item));
        return super.getItemPaint(item, item);
    }
}
…
CandlestickRenderer r = new AnalysisCandlestickRenderer();
chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(r);
```

Console:

```
1: Wed Jan 01 12:00:00 EST 2014
1: Wed Jan 01 12:01:00 EST 2014
1: Wed Jan 01 12:02:00 EST 2014
1: Wed Jan 01 12:03:00 EST 2014
1: Wed Jan 01 12:04:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:00:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:01:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:02:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:03:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:04:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:05:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:06:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:07:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:08:00 EST 2014
0: Wed Jan 01 12:09:00 EST 2014
```

Chart:

[image]